# Kohana: защита от XSS

Tags: xss, php, kohana

Kohana имеет метод http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Security#xss_clean .

```
$my_test = '<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = \'http://google.com\'"></a>';
echo Security::xss_clean($my_test);
```

Получаю:
**ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Security::xss_clean()**

Помогите разобратся с данным методом.Почему там используют javascript?

**Может у кого то есть отличный метод/класс Защиты от XSS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 3.1, такого метода нет. Потому и ошибка.

Чтобы добавить - можно установить модуль [HTMLPurifier](https://github.com/shadowhand/purifier).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию